# How do I make rules within this Tkinter problem?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on this GUI style problem in PyCharm in which I run my main file to have a GUI open as shown in the screenshot.

[image: GUI]

Now, there are a few rules I am having trouble following as this is new to me.

- Use exception handling to deal with invalid age input. So when anything besides an integer is entered, it will clear the 'Age' value, keep the 'Name' and 'Status' selected, and ask to re-enter the age.
- If no status is selected, place 'Unknown' in the proper section of the output file.
- Once 'Save' is clicked, the cursor will be placed in the 'Name' box.

CODE:

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
   def __init__(self, window):

     self.window = window

     self.frame_name = Frame(self.window)

     self.label_name = Label(self.frame_name, text='Name')
     self.entry_name = Entry(self.frame_name)
     self.label_name.pack(padx=5, side='left')
     self.entry_name.pack(padx=5, side='left')
     self.frame_name.pack(anchor='w', pady=10)


     self.frame_age = Frame(self.window)
     self.label_age = Label(self.frame_age, text='Age')
     self.entry_age = Entry(self.frame_age)
     self.label_age.pack(padx=9, side='left')
     self.entry_age.pack(padx=9, side='left')
     self.frame_age.pack(anchor='w', pady=10)


     self.frame_status = Frame(self.window)
     self.label_status = Label(self.frame_status, text='Status')
     self.label_status.pack(padx=5, side='left')

     self.rbtn = StringVar()
     self.rbtn.set('none')
     self.rbutton_student = Radiobutton(self.frame_status,text='Student',variable=self.rbtn,value="Student")
     self.rbutton_student.pack(padx=10, side='left')
     self.rbutton_staff = Radiobutton(self.frame_status,text='Staff',variable=self.rbtn,value="Staff")
     self.rbutton_staff.pack(padx=10, side='left')
     self.rbutton_both = Radiobutton(self.frame_status,text='Both',variable=self.rbtn,value="Both")
     self.rbutton_both.pack(padx=10, side='left')
     self.frame_status.pack(anchor='w', pady=10)

     self.frame_button = Frame(self.window)
     self.button_save = Button(text="Save",command = self.clicked)
     self.button_save.pack(anchor='center')
     self.frame_button.pack(anchor='w',pady=10)

   def clicked(self):
     name = self.entry_name.get()
     age = int(self.entry_age.get())*2
     status = self.rbtn.get()

     with open('data.csv','a') as f:
        f.write(name+","+str(age)+","+status+"\n")
        self.entry_name.delete(0,END)
        self.entry_age.delete(0,END)
        self.rbtn.set('none')
```

Comment: What are the difficulties that hinder you from implementing those rules?  Don't know how to use `try/except`? Don't know how to set focus to an entry box?  It is not hard to do what you want. Also why do you multiply *age* by 2?

Comment: Please focus on a single issue at a time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Here's a simple solution to prevent the user from entering non-numerical values in the "Age" field. This also has nothing to do with the other fields, so those will remain un-modified. The other nice thing about this approach is that you don't have to punish the user for accidentally typing a non-numeric character by forcing them to re-enter text

```
self.entry_age.bind('<Key>', self.validate_age_input)

# define this method somewhere within your main class, similar to 'clicked'
def validate_age_input(self, event):
    key = event.keysym
    allowed_keys = {'BackSpace', 'Delete', 'Up', 'Down', 'Left', 'Right'}
    # check if the key pressed wasn't a number or a deletion
    if not key.isdigit() or key not in allowed_keys:  
        self.bell()  # warning ding
        return 'break'  # dispose of this event
        # (no text will be entered, any existing text remains in place)
```

2. You can simply set the initial value of `self.rbtn` to `'Unknown'` instead of `'none'`, that way if the user presses the "Save" button before selecting a "Status" option, you'll automatically get `'Unknown'` in your output

```
self.rbtn = StringVar()
self.rbtn.set('Unknown')  # or whatever string you want, really!
```

2. *Side Note* -
   You can shorten this up at the declaration like so:

```
self.rbtn = StringVar(value='Unknown')
```

3. You can add a line to `clicked()` to simply `focus()` the "Name" entry again

```
def clicked(self):
    name = self.entry_name.get()
    age = int(self.entry_age.get())*2
    status = self.rbtn.get()

    with open('data.csv','a') as f:
        # f.write(name+","+str(age)+","+status+"\n")
        # a more 'Pythonic' way to handle string interpolation like this is
        # using 'f-strings' - check it out:
        f.write(f'{name},{age},{status}\n'
        # note that the 'f' before the string is not the same 'f' as your
        # file reference ;)

    # these lines don't really need to be in the 'with' block
    self.entry_name.delete(0, END)
    self.entry_age.delete(0, END)
    self.rbtn.set('Unknown')  # remember: this is your new 'default' Status value
    self.entry_name.focus()  # return focus to this Entry
```

Comment: the entry widget has input validation features that will work better than binding on `<Key>`.

Comment: You cannot delete characters in the entry box and move the insertion cursor if using your validation function.  Also empty age can be input which raise exception when `clicked()` is executed.  Using `try/except` in `clicked()` is simplier.

Comment: @BryanOakley True, but those can be cumbersome for beginners. I'll admit this is closer to "quick and dirty", but it has the advantage of simplicity. OP: [here](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-validation/) is some good documentation on input validation in tkinter if you want to do it the "right" way

Comment: @acw1668 That's a good point! I forgot to allow for deletion...that's what I get for rushing. Proper input validation it is, then.

Comment: @JRiggles Thank you! Great work, you really got this down. I just am struggling with the whole age thing still. Is there maybe a simpler way to do with using try/except?

Comment: @icewayflood Try/Except only works if there's actually an exception to catch. You can, of course, `raise` an exception at any time...but you have to check if the input is what you expect anyway, so why bother? The short answer is: there's no *quick* way to tell an `Entry` "Only accept numbers, raise an exception otherwise" - that doesn't mean this *can't* be done - that's where the actual implementation if input validation comes in.